# Bad request with django and javascript ("POST /user_send_info/ HTTP/1.1" 400 98)

Tags: javascript, django

Hi guys I basically wanna get some data using Js and put it in a view in django, but I'm getting bad request  ("POST /user_send_info/ HTTP/1.1" 400 98) when I try to get it, the request gets activated when we click a button

This my Js section

```
<script>
    var DateTime = luxon.DateTime;

    const sendBtns = [...document.getElementsByClassName("send_btn")]
    sendBtns.forEach(btn => btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
        const companyName = btn.getAttribute("company-name")
        const userName = btn.getAttribute("user-name")
        const fullName = btn.getAttribute("full-name")
        const email = btn.getAttribute("email")
        const expireDate = btn.getAttribute("expire-date")
        const version = btn.getAttribute("version")
        const code = btn.getAttribute("code")

        function formatDate(inputDate) {
            const dt = luxon.DateTime.fromISO(inputDate);

            if (dt.isValid) {
                const day = dt.toFormat('dd');
                const monthName = dt.toFormat('LLL');
                const year = dt.toFormat('yyyy');
                return day + '-' + monthName + '-' + year;
            }

            return inputDate;
        }

        const dateFormatted = formatDate(expireDate);

        const info = {
            companyName,
            userName,
            fullName,
            email,
            dateFormatted,
            version,
            code,
        };
        console.log(info)
        fetch('/user_send_info/', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'X-CSRFToken': '{{ csrf_token }}', 
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(info),
        })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(info => {
            console.log('Response from Django:', info);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error('Error to send AJAX request:', error);
        });
    }));
</script>
```

This my View in Django

```
from django.http import JsonResponse

def email_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST' and request.is_ajax():
        info = json.loads(request.body)

        companyName = info.get('companyName')
        userName = info.get('userName')
        fullName = info.get('fullName')
        email = info.get('email')
        expireDate = info.get('dateFormatted')
        version = info.get('version')
        code = info.get('code')
        
        print("##########",companyName)
        print("##########",userName)
        print("##########",fullName)
        print("##########",email)
        print("##########",expireDate)
        print("##########",version)
        print("##########",code)

        
        return JsonResponse({'message': 'Data received correctly.'})

    return JsonResponse({'message': 'No valid request.'}, status=400)
```

And my url looks like this

```
path(
        "user_send_info/",
        email.email_view,
        name='email_view',
    ),
```

I don't really understand what could be wrong with my code, so if someone can help me to find why I'm getting this error it would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

Remove  `and request.is_ajax()`, it is an old feature that I suspect is causing your condition to fail. Newer versions of Django don't support it.

Your condition should be:

```py
if request.method == 'POST':
```